# MySQL PDO query with CONTAINS parameter?

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have

```
$query = "SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    WHERE position = ?
    AND (CONTAINS(first_name, ?)
    OR CONTAINS(last_name, ?))";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);

$stmt->bindValue(1, $position, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, "%{".$q."}%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(3, "%{".$q."}%", PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute()or die("error");
```

The script keeps on dying.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LIKE:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE position = ?
AND first_name LIKE ?
OR last_name LIKE ?
```

Comment: I tried using the LIKE operator but it wasn't returning enough rows. I'm guessing it was too simple of a query. Could I use mysqli in conjunction with CONTAINS instead?

Comment: CONTAINS is not MySQL function, use like

Answer (score 0):

`CONTAINS` is SQL server syntax, not MySQL. use `LIKE`

Comment: I tried using the LIKE operator but it wasn't returning enough rows. I'm guessing it was too simple of a query. Could I use mysqli in conjunction with CONTAINS instead?

Comment: NO, you can't...CONTAINS is SQL server syntax